# Drag an item in listview to a form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop, telerik

I have two forms; one of them is containing listview, and another one is just a form.

I want to make a thing :
If I drag an item in listview to a Form, a messagebox would be pop up.
and the message would be text of the item.

However I don't know why 'SelectedItem' is null. When I trace the SelectedItem, it was null.

I found I have to use MouseDown and DragDrop events, but I have no idea how to use.

First one is the listview's code :

```
rListCtrl.MouseDown += rListCtrl_MouseDown;
rListCtrl.DragDrop += rListCtrl_DragDrop;


private void rListCtrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new STringBuilder();
    sb.Append(radListView1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    testName = sb.ToString();
}

private void rListCtrl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e){
{
    MessageBox.Show(testName);
}
```

radListView1 is the name of listview.

Comment: What is radListView1?

Comment: that is a name of the listview

Comment: Ok, and what is rListCtrl?

Comment: Read the vendor\s documentation. [ListViewDragDropService](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/listview/drag-and-drop/listviewdragdropservice)

Comment: Possible that `MouseDown` fires _before_ the Item is selected. That's why it would still be null. There should be an event like "SelectionChanged" (or the like) , however.

Comment: @JQSOFT Good resource, but mind OP's requirement to drop the element into a Form. So that would cover only one half of the question.

Comment: You need to DoDragDrop(RadListView.SelectedItem) in the MouseDown event of that RadListView, and handle the DragDrop event of the second Form.

Comment: I solved dragdrop. but i want to do the message's text would be a text of selecteditem of listview. but always selecteditem is null...

Comment: I have an idea by using public field in form2, see my answer for detail.

Comment: Are you enabling the _AllowDrop_ properties of both source and target controls?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `SelectedItem` is null, is that the Item only gets selected when you actually perform a click, not a mere `MouseDown`.
You can, however, use the `IndexFromPoint` method to get the Item the mouse had been placed on when the `MouseDown` Event was evoked:

```
private void radListView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = radListView1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    radListView1.SelectedIndex = index;
    testName = radListView1.Items[index].ToString();
}

private void rListCtrl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e){
{
    MessageBox.Show(testName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(f.data!= string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(f.data);
            f.data = string.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string data = string.Empty;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.ItemDrag += doDaragItem;
    }

    private void doDaragItem(Object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        data = e.Item.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: By using event listView1.ItemDrag; Then drag an item from form2.listView1 into form1 , the method Form1_MouseEnter will be active. also you can check if the data is empty, then show noting in form1.

Comment: I have updated the code so that the form1 message box will always show after drag.

Answer (score 0):

Ron,

RadListView from the Telerik UI from WinForms suite handles the whole drag and drop operation by its ListViewDragDropService. Its PreviewDragOver event allows you to control on what targets the item(s) being dragged can be dropped on. The PreviewDragDrop event allows you to get a handle on all the aspects of the drag and drop operation, the source (drag) list view, the destination (target) control, as well as the item being dragged. Additional information is available in the following help article: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/listview/drag-and-drop/listviewdragdropservice
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/listview/drag-and-drop/drag-and-drop-using-raddragdropservice

You can also combine the RadDragDropService and OLE drag-and-drop functionality: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/listview/drag-and-drop/combining-raddragdropservice-and-ole-drag-and-drop

As to the specific code snippet, indeed, if you don't have a selected item in RadListView, the code in the MouseDown event won't extract the item's text. You need to get the element under the mouse and set the item as selected:

```
        private void radListView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SimpleListViewVisualItem elementUnderMouse = this.radListView1.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(e.Location) as SimpleListViewVisualItem;
        if (elementUnderMouse != null)
        {
            this.radListView1.SelectedItem = elementUnderMouse.Data ;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(radListView1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
        {
            testName = sb.ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(testName);
    }
```

I hope this information helps.